# Wait until zip fully written then continue, Bash Script

Tags: bash, ftp, zip, corrupt

I've been trying to zip a file and then upload it by FTP using a bash script, but it's uploading a corrupt zip file. I've had a look around and I'm trying to use lsof | grep to confirm the file is complete but I'm not really sure what I'm doing.

So I've got

```
cd /var/test/tobezipped
zip -r test.zip *
FOLDER="/var/test/tobezipped"
ZIPS=$(ls $FOLDER)
for F in $zips ; do
  while [ -n "$(lsof | grep $F" ] ; do
  sleep 1
done
ftp -n <<EOF
open myserver
user user pass
put test.zip
EOF
done
```

and test.zip is corrupt at the time it's being uploaded, so on the other server it's not readable but on the server it's zipped on it's all good by the time I check it.

Any kind of advice is appreciated, I'm pretty new to this sort of thing and tried to search around heaps to find a solution, not too sure I'm going in the right direction. Thanks in advance.

Comment: the zip looks to be OK, try adding `binary` as a separate line inside your `ftp here-doc`, just before the `put` command. Good luck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the man page:

> **put local-file [remote-file]**
>                    Store a local file on the remote machine.  If remote-file is left unspecified, the local file name is used after
>   processing according to
>                    any ntrans or nmap settings in naming the remote file.  File transfer uses the current settings for type, format, mode,
>   and structure.

I guess the problem is that you are not transfering files in BINARY mode.

Try this:

```
ftp -n <<EOF
open myserver
user user pass
binary
put test.zip
EOF
```

Comment: That works perfectly, thank you so much! I can't even upvote because not enough reputation but have an imaginary one. Thank you again mate

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
PID=$(pgrep zip)
while [[ ( -d /proc/$PID) ) && ( -z `grep zombie /proc/$PID/status` ) ]]; do
    sleep 1
done
```